# 'SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry' when trying to install 17.10

Tags: live-usb, 17.10, squashfs

Running Ubuntu 17.10 from the boot USB I'm unable to run applications such as settings, the actual installer or Firefox. Starting from desktop nothing happens. Starting from the applications I get an Input/Output error.

When trying to restart I get these errors: https://postimg.org/image/xlpq96wx1/

If I try to install Ubuntu I run into another error message after the third step of the installer (the one where I can select to download updates while installing Ubuntu as well as to install third-party software): 'ubi-partman failed with exit code 2. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog.'

I select Quit and shut down the machine via the power button. Then, this happens: https://postimg.org/image/gxy86x7d1/